# Pagination on asp:DataGrid does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, pagination

I am trying to add pagination to my Gridview. I have added the following to the properties:

```
<table id="myTable" class="table tbody" runat="server" visible="false">
     <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <asp:DataGrid ID="myGrid" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped tbody" Visible="false"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                      AllowPaging="True"
                      AllowCustomPaging="true"
                      ForeColor="black"
                      HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true"
                      HeaderStyle-ForeColor="black"
                      GridLines="None"
                      EnableViewState="false" />
             </td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

The result set is returning 22 rows and it is correctly showing the first 10 on the first page, but I do not have any option to move to the next page. There are not numbers or arrows to press to move to page 2, etc.

Can anyone help me with what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should remove the `Allow Custom paging property` and set a `PageSize` property as per your requirement. Then you must add `OnPageIndexChanging` event to your grid. So for example:

```
AllowPaging="true" PageSize="8" OnPageIndexChanging="stockTakeGrid_PageIndexChanging"
```

So in the code behind you must also handle the above event for example:

```
        protected void stockTakeGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        stockTakeGrid.DataSource = ViewState["stockDetails"];
        stockTakeGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        stockTakeGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        stockTakeGrid.DataBind();
    }
```

When you are initially loading the grid set your page index to **0**

Comment: what would my viewstate be?

Comment: anything you want to name it. Then just call the same viewstate name to extract data from it. I use ViewState to minimize the number of database calls i need to make during the lifecycle of a page.